# AWS VPC Instance NO OUTBOUND connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, vpc, outbound

In AWS, i have created a VPC for the first time (with a Public Subnet inside), then i put my VM inside inside the Subnet. Everything is fine, except:

- my VM can not make any OUTBOUND connections to the Internet. *(But it can be reached via Internet).*

My VM has an associated EIP already.

And here are some info (as far as i understand):

**VPC**
CIDR: 10.0.0.0/16
Route Table: 1 (rtb-xxxxxxx)
Network ACL: 1 (acl-xxxxxxx)

**Route Table**
10.0.0.0/16 | local
0.0.0.0/0 | igw-xxxxxxxx
Subnet Assoc.: 1 (subnet-xxxxxxxx - 10.0.1.0/24)

**Subnet**
VPC: vpc-xxxxxxxx
Route Table: rtb-xxxxxxx
Network ACL: acl-xxxxxxxx

**Network ACL**
Inbound: Allowed All
Outbound: Allowed All **
Subnet Assoc.: 1 (subnet-xxxxxxxx - 10.0.1.0/24)

**Instance (VM Itself)**
Internal Firewall: Turned Off
EIP: Public EIP Assigned.
Private IP: 10.0.1.100

---

But then, there is NO OUTBOUND connection to Internet. What should i do please.

Comment: What about the Security Group associated with the instance?  Does it allow outbound traffic?

Comment: The fact that it can be "reached" via the Internet means that outbound traffic is working successfully. The problem appears to be related to outbound-initiated traffic. That would normally be due to the outbound rules on the Security Group. What are you doing to initiate the outbound connection? If you start another instance in the same subnet (with a default AMI and a public IP address), does it work?